# Enabling / Disabling ToolStripMenuItem when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripmenu, toolstripitem

I've two forms (called form1 as mdi container and form2) with an opentoolstripmenuitem in form1, when opentoolstripmenuitem clicked form2 called and opentoolstripmenuitem become disable, but when i click closebox in the top right of form2 the opentoolstripmenu still disable, i want it to enable again when closebox clicked.

Here my code in form1 :

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();
    newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
    newMDIChild.Show();            
}
```

any advice??

Comment: Add a "closing" event handler on `newMDIChild` that re-enables your menu item.

Comment: You can do this programmatically in `openToolStripMenuItem_Click`.

Comment: Why disable it at all?  Why not simply activate the open instance if it's clicked again?

Comment: can you give me specific code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click handler, create a handler for the Closing or Closed event for Form2:

```
newMDIChild.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(newMDIChild_FormClosed);
```

and

```
void newMDIChild_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
        openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Just use ShowDialog() on form and enable it after Showdialog

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
newMDIChild.ShowDialog(); 
openToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;           
}
```

The next code after showdialog will not be executed until the dialog is close

Hope it works

Thanks